# Not able to see source code while analyzing dump file in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, crash-dumps

I double click on a .dmp file and it opens in Visual Studio 2012.

I have tried specifying the source code directories inside the Properties of the solution as mentioned in this post:

[Analyzing Crash dumps in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12252407/analyzing-crash-dumps-in-visual-studio)

When I click on "Debug with Mixed", It shows me the exception that occurred and also the line number and file name where exception occurred. But then, it prompts to break the debugging because it can't find the source files[image: Dmp File - specified in project properties]

How can I see the source code here and all the variable values?

Answer (score 1):

Typically I have the Visual Studio opened with the right solution loaded, then I do File -> Open for the dump file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the symbols that you are loading corresponds to the source as well as the dump.